# How do I see and replicate the R default Makevars configuration?

Tags: c++, r, makefile, rcpp, tmb

I do not have a `~/.R/Makevars` file and

```
> tools::makevars_user()
character(0)
> tools::makevars_site()
character(0)
```

Yet, `R` must be reading the configuration from somewhere as `.cpp` files containing `Rcpp` exports in the package `src` subdirectory compile fine.

I am interested to know how to write a `Makefile.win` in the `src` directory so that `Rcpp` files continue to compile, alongside `TMB` `.cpp` files. Currently a makefile like:

```
all: fn1.dll fn2.dll

fn1.dll: fn1.cpp
    Rscript --vanilla -e "TMB::compile('fn1.cpp')"

fn2.dll: fn2.cpp
    Rscript --vanilla -e "TMB::compile('fn2.cpp')"

clean:
    rm -rf *o
```

works fine to compile `TMB` files, and is in fact suggested by: https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/issues/43

I tried to modify the `makefile` suggested by Dirk [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735661/2109289) but had no luck to replicate `R`'s default behaviour even with a fresh new test package.

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Comment: Rule Number One: Don't write a Makefile, just write a Makevars snippet.  See "Writing R Extensions" for details, and a thousands of CRAN packages as examples.

Comment: As for your question itself:  `$(RHOME)/etc/Makeconf` is where it is at.

Comment: Thanks. I hope to transition to a `Makevars` snippet but I just need to know how to integrate the `TMB` bit into this.

Comment: Ah, for my system it is in `$(RHOME)/etc/x64/Makeconf` and `$(RHOME)/etc/i386/Makeconf`

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea how to use `Makevars` to do what I want, which is to essentially:

1. Do a normal default `make` in Rstudio (Windows 7) via `Build and Reload` package for all `Rcpp` export files. Under the hood, this calls `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` then proceeds to run the other package building commands.
2. Do another `make` using Rstudio `Build and Reload`, except now it reads the `Makefile` that only compiles  the `TMB` code.

However, I do have a work-around. Essentially, the [R extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) states that:

> Something close to the default behavior could be replicated with the following `src/install.libs.R' file:
>
> ...

Since, the code to compile the `TMB` `.cpp` files are simply `R` commands, it is easy enough to integrate them into such a file:

```
# replicate default R
files <- Sys.glob(paste("*", SHLIB_EXT, sep=''))
libarch <- if (nzchar(R_ARCH)) paste('libs', R_ARCH, sep='') else 'libs'
dest <- file.path(R_PACKAGE_DIR, libarch)
dir.create(dest, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
file.copy(files, dest, overwrite = TRUE)

# now do TMB files
cpp_files <- list.files('./TMB/', full.names = T, pattern = '*.cpp')

for (f in cpp_files) {
    TMB::compile(f)
}

files <- Sys.glob(paste("./TMB/*", SHLIB_EXT, sep=''))
libarch <- if (nzchar(R_ARCH)) paste('libs', R_ARCH, sep='') else 'libs'
dest <- file.path(R_PACKAGE_DIR, libarch)
dir.create(dest, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
file.copy(files, dest, overwrite = TRUE)
```

This file reads and compiles all `TMP` type `.cpp` files, stored in the sub-directory `<pkgdir>/src/TMB`, and then copies all subsequent `.dll`s in `<pkgdir>/src/` and `<pkgdir>/src/TMB` to the installation directory of the package.

Note, [it is possible, but possibly very difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594574/2109289) to use `Makevars` to get a compilation done when the TMB files are stored in a subdirectory. Dirk recommended the example in the [matrix package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html), but I had no luck modifying the code there to do what I want.