# A package that needs compilation cannot be installed with a different name

Tags: r, compilation, r-glue

I have a [github clone](https://github.com/oganm/glue.1.3.1) of the `glue` R package for reasons. The name of this package is changed into `glue.1.3.1` in this repository from its `DESCRIPTION` file for similar reasons. As a control group, I have an [identical repository](https://github.com/oganm/glue) but this one's name is not changed in any way

If I do

```r
devtools::install_github('oganm/glue.1.3.1')
```

the installation will fail

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘glue.1.3.1’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘glue.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

If I do

```
devtools::install_github('oganm/glue)
```

the installation will be successful.

If I do the same thing to most other packages, there are no problems but it seems like the source code of pacakges that need compilation, the change in the package name causes problems. For instance, you can repeat the issue with dplyr [here](https://github.com/oganm/dplyr.0.5.0)

The question is, what causes this issue? What do I need to do so that I can reliably change names of packages that require compilation?

Comment: Is this where you need to also change the [dynlib](https://github.com/oganm/glue.1.3.1/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L26) ? And as the NAMESPACE is generated by roxygen you probably have to use the [tags](https://github.com/oganm/glue.1.3.1/blob/master/R/glue.R#L59)

Comment: It does seem to solve the problem. Hmm so I guess I'd need to look at all dynlib mentions in the code and replace with the new name, unless I don't run roxygen again.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976036/how-to-use-usedynlib-correctly-in-an-r-package-namespace-file

Comment: dynlib does not actually solve all the issues. it seems like different packages may have different needs in this regard. glue works fine with just changing dynlibs, dplyr doesnt